# iCloud Photo Library content fills up 16GB phone

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

My wife has an iPhone with little storage and has iCloud Photo Library enabled on her Mac and iPhone. Recently it's been hitting the limit of the phones storage and breaking other apps.

I would have thought that Photos would be smart enough to keep on thumbnails of the oldest photos, but about 80% of the phone storage is Photos.app and it just keeps downloading more.

What's the best way to handle this? The only options I have come up with are (1) curating photos and videos harder - deleting less good photos etc. (2) disabling iCloud Photo Library completely and only sync certain shared albums.

Comment: An option is also to increase your iCloud size.  Are you open to doing that?

Comment: There's plenty of cloud storage - it's the phone local storage which is maxing out. Feels like Photos isn't optimizing the images properly.

Comment: I understand now, thanks.  iCloud is a syncing solution so it keeps copies everywhere you're signed-in.  I believe you've already thought of the only options available to you (apart from buying another iPhone with more internal storage).